# lat and long gps locations inside a rectangle

Tags: android, gps, location

This is my code objective:  I want an android application to start to trigger connecting to server and sending the latitude and longitude only when the phone (being used in a car) is within a road area ( say an area 1km x 30m ). It is continuously listening to its location but will start sending to server once it enters the area and will continuously send and will stop only once it exit the area.

A good answer i received for this:
"create two location, a NorthWest location and a SouthEast location that represent your box. In your onLocationChanged method, compare the new location with the corners, such that (l.lat > se.lat && l.lat < nw.lat) and (l.lon < se.lon && l.lon > nw.lon) where "l" is the newest location from the callback, "se" is the south east corner of your boundary and "nw" is the north west corner of your bounder. If it meets the 4 above conditions, then you send to your server"

I think this is applicable when a pair of the sides of the rectangular area are parallel to the latitude(equator) and the other pair of the sides parallel to the longitude lines (meridian). What if the rectangular area's sides are not parallel to the latitude and longitude lines . How can I meet my objective?

Comment: yes please check your options here http://paulbourke.net/geometry/insidepoly/

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a pending intent for proximity alert.
PendingIntent broadcastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID,
    associatedIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
// Add the proximity alert.
mLocationManager.addProximityAlert(Latitude, Longitude, ProximityAlertRadius,
    TimeOut, broadcastPendingIntent);
```

Add a broadcast receiver to receive your intent.

Comment: Thanks Navin. Would that make a rectangle or a circle instead? As per what I read that will make a circle if i am not mistaken.

Comment: Yes that's correct a radius will form a circle area. Is there a better way to meet the rectangular area objective? appreciate the time Navin.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading a part of the solutions in this [website](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/insidepoly/) the possible solution i selected is the Solution 3 (2D):

I tried to translate this in to a java code. so far below is my code ( not tested and polished yet - may have basic errors and the values of longitudes and latitudes are not real )

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {                     
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        String txt = "Latitude:" + loc.getLatitude() + "/nLongitude:" +  loc.getLongitude();
        Log.i("GeoLocation", "My current location is:\n " + txt);
        tv.setText("My current location is:\n" + txt);
        String msg = loc.getLongitude() + "\n" + loc.getLatitude() + "\n"
           + loc.getTime();

        double lat0 = 0.2;
        double long0 = 0.3;
        double lat1 = 1.2;
        double long1 = 1.3;
        double lat2 = 1.2;
        double long2 = 1.3;
        double lat3 = 1.2;
        double long3 = 1.3;
        double rel1 = (loc.getLongitude()- long0)*(lat1 - lat0)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat0)*(long1-long0));
        double rel2 = (loc.getLongitude()- long1)*(lat2 - lat1)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat1)*(long2-long1));
        double rel3 = (loc.getLongitude()- long2)*(lat3 - lat2)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat2)*(long3-long2));
        double rel4 = (loc.getLongitude()- long3)*(lat0 - lat3)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat3)*(long0-long3));

        if (rel1 <= 0 && rel2 <= 0 && rel3 <= 0 && rel4 <= 0 )
        {
            try
            {
            connect("IP address", 27960);
            send("CMD_HELLO");
            send(msg);
            send("CMD_QUIT");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        else
        {
            tv.setText("Current location is outside the road network");

        }
    }
```

Please comment for corrections and suggestions